# Why this doesn't work in ZSH? alias lazy='touch $1; open $1'

Tags: zsh

Tried using && in place of ;

Tried also [[]] and $()

It's probably nothing but it drives me crazy.. Care to help?

BTW, I know this works fine:

```
lazy()
{
    touch $1
    open $1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aliases don't accept arguments like that. Any arguments you pass after the alias, such as `lazy moop` will run `touch $1; open $1 moop`.

You should just go with defining this as a function, as it actually works like you want it to.

Comment: Hmm, that explains it indeed. Thanks!